# Dell Studio 1537 display doesn't work anymore. Can anyone help?

Tags: laptop, display, dell-studio

I have a laptop from Dell, a Studio 1537, model PP33L which I bought a year and a week ago (so no more warranty!).
Since yesterday, the screen isn't showing any image anymore. The light works (I can regulate the intensity) and the sound of Windows as well. It also works on an external display, but the screen of the notebook stays grey...
Does anyone have an explanation to this? Could it just be a connection problem inside the computer?
Thanks for your answers.

Edit: Maybe I should add that I just travelled 10 hours in a plane with the laptop in my suitcase. Maybe a shock?

Comment: Have you tried calling Dell and begging them to fix it a week after Warranty, or would that just be futile?

Comment: I already tried. They could give me a year more warranty for something like 160€, then they could eventually fix my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I decided to pull out the plastic protection that's over the keyboard, after unscrewing the 2 screws under the battery.
And I discovered the little cable wasn't fully sticked in the hole (on the motherboard...), explaining why the colors couldn't be transported to the display!
So everything works fine again. Hope it helps other!

Comment: Haha, I was literally just about to suggest that as an answer! Then I looked down and saw you beat me to it by 19 seconds :) Anyway, glad to hear you fixed it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I thought it must be something like that, cause it worked on a external display, and the LEDs and the display in general were working. I'm happy it works, one year for a laptop is a bit short!